# How to timestamp of a city

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am able to find the timestamp of an current location using below code.

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

```
       var timestamp=position.coords.timestamp;

    });
```

However is it possible to find the timestamp of an address or city. I can able to find the latitude and longitude of the city, but not able to find the timestamp.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': "chennai" }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

               var position= new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),             
                           results[0].geometry.location.lng())

            }
        });
```

How to find the timestamp of an address using the latitude and longitude values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may request the [**timezone-API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

Answer (score 0):

there is no API by Google as such where you can set latitude and longitude as parameters in the request and get the timestamp in the response. There is a timezone API offered by Google but that too takes timestamp as a input parameter which is of no use in your case.

The best option here is to use a third party API that takes the input parameters as latitude and longitude and gives the response in timestamp. You can use that result in a variable and display it inside a info window in your map. Here in a [link](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone) to one such API for XML and [this](http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&username=demo) one for JSON.